# Read a binary file in Scala

Tags: file, scala

I have some binary files which are written by a `Java` application in the following way:

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(complete_path_to_file)));

dos.writeInt(aInteger);
dos.writeLong(aLong);
dos.writeFloat(aFloat);

dos.close();
```

Now, I'd like to read this kind files in a `Scala` framework but I really don't have any ideas about how to do that.

Could you help me?

Comment: Why don't you read them in exactly the same way you will do in java? (with DataInputStream and such stuff?)

Comment: Yes I could, but I was wondering whether it exists a Scala-idiomatic way to do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667714/parsing-of-binary-data-with-scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading it using the same classes and methods you'd use in Java is probably going to be the most error-free, as you have a direct correspondence between read and write.

You can also use [Scala I/O](https://github.com/scala-incubator/scala-io), which is the best library for file I/O for Scala -- and a possible addition to the standard library in the future.

Then there's [sbinary](http://github.com/harrah/sbinary), where less concern is given to I/O itself, and more concern is given to describing the binary record.

Comment: Scala I/O had no commits for 3 years...