# Configurable and reusable data file parser for Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, configuration, csv

I am interested in making a data file parser. It should be a reusable and configurable data parser. The description of the data format and some rules on how to parse would be in a configuration file (maybe a .xml file). The input file to be parsed is a plain text file and the output file will be a .csv file. So every time I want to parse a file I would only write some data description file and/or mapping file, without the need to change the parsing logic. Do you know some parsers that can do what I want?

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644737/are-there-any-java-frameworks-for-binary-file-parsing

Answer (score 0):

may be you want [this](http://java-source.net/open-source/parser-generators)

Answer (score 0):

If your "data files" are binary files, you might be interested in things like http://harmony.apache.org/subcomponents/classlibrary/asn1_framework.html or http://sourceforge.net/projects/jac-asn1/