# Java or C++ equivalents to Preon?

Tags: java, c++, binary, preon

[*Preon*](https://github.com/preon/preon) is a Java library meant for creating binary codecs: you simply place annotations in a class' data members regarding their correspondence with bit fields (e.g. number of bits to use for certain field) and, based on such class, the library builds a Codec object that is able to create instances of the class reading their data from a binary input stream.

Due to licensing issues (it is distributed under GPL), I cannot use it.

Are there any libraries with equivalent or similar functionality, either in Java or in C++?

Comment: Can’t you use precompiled GPL-licensed libraries by referencing them as jar files without being contaminated by the license? I always thought that dynamic linking (which this amounts to) was allowed under the GPL (unlike static linking). This might be outdated information, though.

Comment: the general consensus i've seen is that you _can't_ use GPL java libraries without your code also being GPL.  granted, this is where the GPL gets a little nebulous.  LGPL and "GPL with classpath exception" is generally considered safe (see my answer).

Comment: jthahlborn is completely right. Other than, you *can* also get a commercial license for Preon.

Comment: @WilfredSpringer How can I get a commercial license for Preon?

Comment: Dirk Jäckel, contact me (wilfredspringer at gmail dot com)

Comment: link is dead (well, it requires authentication)

Comment: Link fixed, now pointing to preon's github repository

Answer (score 10, accepted):

looking at the [license](http://preon.codehaus.org/license.html) page, the preon library is "GNU General Public License, version 2, **with the Classpath Exception**", which is important.  that allows you to use the library in binary form *without* your application also being GPL.

Comment: Reading the license I get the impression that I'd have to check every source file of Preon whether it contains the classpath exception. Did you check that every file does? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @DirkJäckel - nope, i didn't check every file.  i was not the one planning on using the library.

Comment: The license has been changed to MIT, which is much more permissive.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Java Binary Block Parser library](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser), it allows to make bit field parsing and mapping to class fields